# Encrypt Filenames - I have no idea what it is and where to use it. Please explain

Tags: security, encryption

I saw in 7zip checkbox to Encrypt Filename and than someone told me to encrypt filename and encrypt the file. What does it mean filename encryption?

Comment: Sec, I've answered your question but it probably should have been on one of our sister sites, since it's not really related to programming per se. Hence I've "nudged" it over to SuperUser. Don't worry, it shouldn't disappear. Rather, it will get migrated over to the sister site where it's more appropriate, unless other close voters are less forgiving than I :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are *two* levels of encryption you can use in 7zip (and some other archivers, I would imagine).

---

The first is to encrypt the actual *data* being stored so that you can't get that data (easily) without the key.

However, in that case, you can still *open the archive and view the file names (i.e., the directory hierarchy) within it.* It's only once you try to get at the file *content* will you need the key.

If you don't even want people to see those *file names* without the key, you should encrypt those as well.

---

In terms of encrypted-content files, here's one I prepared earlier. You can see that, even though it's encrypted, I can still see the file names (it will ask for the key when I try to extract/open one of those files).

[image]

---

Compare that to one where I also encrypted the file names. With that one, it won't even let me *see* the file names until I enter the password.

[image]

---

It's handy to have the extra layer of protection if the file names themselves may give away unwanted information. For example, if you're hiding your porn collection where your wife can't see it, you *don't* want her opening up the archive and seeing file names indicating what's in there. Even if she can't see the actual images, you'll still be in a lot of trouble.

Needless to say, you should use a *third* layer of protection there as well. Even if you encrypt the content *and* file names, you probably don't want to keep it in a file called `PornIAmHidingFromMyWife.7z`.

Or, of course, you could use the ultimate protective layer and not have the porn in the first place :-)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  why do you think google drive look for filename and decides if they should check this file on their security antiviruses machines? If i will upload a malicious file with known name it will be blocked but not if I encrypt it's name.

Comment: Google has nearly unlimited computing power, so once they detect a malicious file once, they can protect all their users from being infected by simply scanning an archive file for that file.

Comment: Only by seeing the filename? They can't extract the file. If you malicious filename and one without.  Don't make filename encryption and you will that one will be scanned and other won't.

Comment: @SecQuestionnA Does Google actually do that? Make it a separate question if you really want an answer.

Comment: Really good answer thanks for taking the time to do screenshots, you rock !